# Dropzone error in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dropzone.js, dropzone

I use Dropzone in my CI project. However, I cannot manage it and my files do not upload. It even does not pass image name to variable, as it gives NULL while inserting the database.

[image]

Here is my view:

```
<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
  $("div#dropzone").dropzone({ 
    url: base_url + 'cars/addpic',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    paramName: "files",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    dictDefaultMessage: "<span class='mif-file-upload mif-3x'></span> <br>Faykkari sechin gorek"
  });

</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function addpic() {
    $config['upload_path']   = './assets/img/cars/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size'] = '25000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('files'))
    {
        //for multiple
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
            $_FILES['filee']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['filee']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['filee']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['filee']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];



            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('filee')){
                $manyimages = '';
            } else {
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $manyimages[] = $fileData['file_name'];
            }
        } 

        $manymanyimages= implode(',', $manyimages);
    }
```

and then I pass this data to the main function where all data is uploaded to the database.

```
public function create($manymanyimages) {

    //some other stuff here

    $data = array(             
        'photos' => $manymanyimages
    );

    $this->cars_model->add_car($data);
    redirect('');
}
```

Comment: Tip: You are using initializing the $config twice `$this->upload->initialize($config);` Only need to use `$this->load->library('upload', $config);`

Comment: I've also never seen a `do_upload()` nested in a `do_upload()` - I don't believe that will work - nor assigning the $_FILES array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code; I think your main issue was the nested `do_upload()` and improper dz handling of errors.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/cars/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size'] = '25000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $manyimages = array();
    $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
        $_FILES['filee']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['filee']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['filee']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['filee']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filee')) {
            $this->output->set_status_header(500);
            $this->output->set_output(strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors()));
        } else {
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $manyimages[] = $fileData['file_name'];
        }
    }
    $manymanyimages = implode(',', $manyimages);
    echo $manymanyimages;
```

Comment: Now it workes for sending photos, however it still does not pass names to another function :(

Comment: well you never included that in your code... my code and your code end at the same point... so i'm not sure how you want me to figure that one out.

Comment: Images are actually uploading to the folder './assets/img/cars/' . However, I cannot get $manymanyimages from another function.

Comment: again: do you get your images echoed via `echo $manymanyimages;`??

Comment: it is important to see that we are getting proper output there

Comment: you mean names?

Comment: yea does it echo as you expect? what is the var_dump of that variable in the addpic() func

Comment: `$manymanyimages = implode(',', $manyimages);
    echo $manymanyimages;` it echoes something you just have to know where to look. e.g. the network panel and click the ajax request and then find the preview button... this is really basic stuff

Comment: I did it, and it echoes the filenames. https://mega.nz/#!e1ZDmQgC!XLxonlGzWAWwH0GqWO1WR_EoqSopAQ7Ll7FgsLgDT9M here is the screenshot

Comment: i wish i could help you man I just don't see any reason for the too few argument error at all. maybe send over your full controller.